# Mass Upload of Categories

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-tree

I have around 100 new categories to add to a website, ideally I'd like to go about it as efficiently as possible. Is there any way or perhaps a free extention that will allow adding of new categories on mass in Magento?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously taken a look at this extension [Category Import / Export](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-category-import-export.html)

Might be something you could use.

*No stocks, interest or anything in the provide extension